# How quickly do arithmetic progressions mix modulo a prime?

Tags: number-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ denote the sequence defined by:
$$
X_n = c \cdot n(\mod m),
\quad
c\sim U[\mathbb{Z}_m]
$$
where $m$ is prime.
We ask - how quickly does this sequence mix ?
Formally, what is known about the discrepancy of this sequence as a function of $n$?

On one hand, the work of Niederreiter shows that the m-th discrepancy of such a sequence with a random seed $c$ satisfies $\mathbf{E}_c[D_m] < \log(m)/m$, even if $m$ is not prime - i.e. the discrepancy is very small when the length of the sequence hits the order of the ring.
In fact, when $m$ is prime we have a better bound because $D_m = 1/m$ for all $c\neq 0$ (the sequence cycles exactly through all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_m^*$).
Thus for prime $m$ we have $\mathbf{P}_c( D_m(X) < 1/m ) \geq 1 - 1/m$.

Yet, it is not clear how "quickly" this sequence mixes as a function of $n$ for $n<m$.
For example if $c=1$ then this sequence will be a very "stubborn" mixer - with discrepancy decaying only linearly with $n$,
because $X_n$ will still leave an interval of size $m-n$ without any element in the sequence so $D_n > (m-n)/m = 1 - n/m$.
However, for a random $c$ one could expect $D_n$ to decay much faster, perhaps even as log(n)/n as above.